# Turn on MergeOption.NoTracking for OData (WCF Data Services)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services, odata

I have an OData endpoint that is strictly read-only.  I would like to get the extra performance improvement by setting MergeOption.NoTracking.

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2012/03/01/blast-from-the-past-great-post-on-using-the-object-cache-on-the-client.aspx) seems to suggest that it is possible, but no example is given.

Does anyone know how to turn this on for all of my entities in WCF Data Services (OData)?

I can't seem to find the point where I can access the datasets to turn it on...

If at all possible, I would like to turn this on in my OData service (rather than make all my clients have to know to pass in this parameter (if that is even possible for an OData client).

**NOTE:** This is not a question for how to turn it on for normal WCF.

Answer (score 2):

The post is talking about tracking on the client side (DataServiceContext) and you seem to want to disable tracking on the server side. Since the DataSource is created for each request I am not sure how big overhead the tracking adds - the entities are only added to the ObjectStateManager. Anyways I think it is possible to do what you want to do if you overwrite DataService[T].CreateDataSource() method. In this method you would return your context derived from the ObjectContext class. Now you would have to modify all the ObjectQueries that return entities from the ObjectContext so that they are created with MergeOption.NoTracking parameter. I you really think it is worth it I would first try this on one EntitySet to see how big the benefit would be.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out, and it did have an ever so slight improvement to performance...  sometimes.

```
protected override YourEnityContextHere CreateDataSource()
{
    YourEnityContextHere dataSource = base.CreateDataSource();
    TurnOffChangeTracking(dataSource);
    return dataSource;
}

static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> objSetProps;
private static void TurnOffChangeTracking(YourEnityContextHere dataSource)
{
    if(objSetProps == null)
        objSetProps = dataSource.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObjectSet<>));

    foreach (PropertyInfo objSetProp in objSetProps)
    {
        ObjectQuery objSet = (ObjectQuery)objSetProp.GetValue(dataSource, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null);
        objSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
    }
}
```